# Problems with Xubuntu 16.04 and Intel/Nvidia graphic card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, intel-graphics

I have a notebook Santech t67 with the following features : CPU intel core i7-6700HQ, 16 Gb RAM, Nvidia GeForce GTX 970M + intel integrated card. I installed Xubuntu 16.04 in dual boot with Windows 10 without problems. I have a problem ( sorry for the repetition ) regarding the management of dedicated Nvidia video card and integrated Intel card. I installed the proprietary Nvidia and Intel drivers and I set the Intel one to improve the autonomy of the pc. The system works perfectly, only when I turn it off or reboot it freezes in a black screen with a white dash in the top left corner, forcing me to force it to close. If I use the Nvidia card this does not happen ( the computer turns off and restarts normally) . Someone has the same problem or know a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen at all when you disable the option to save your session upon Shutdown? Maybe play around with the hibernation/sleep options a little. It sounds like it might be linked to this particular problem.

Comment: The option you mentioned is disabled. As I said in the main post, this problem happens only if I use Intel card. I've just tried again switching to Nvidia card and the system turn off and reboot normally without freezeing.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem with my [MSIGE62VR](https://us.msi.com/Laptop/GE62VR-Apache-Pro-6th-Gen-GTX-1060.html#hero-overview), the fix was to add:

```
acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"
```

in the kernel parameters.

You can find more details [here](http://www.castoriscausa.com/posts/freezes-linux-gpu-acpi)